# How to add asset description from Kusto table properties?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-explorer, azure-purview

I added a `docString` property to my Kusto table so I would have the table description easily in handy. My question from Microsoft Purview is if there is a way to automate when is a Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) table asset to populate the Asset Description from this `docString` property.

Even a Powershell script would solve this problem for now.

Example:

Asset Description:

[image]

Kusto table docString property:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution but using Python instead, I used the libraries below:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, ClientSecretCredential 
from azure.mgmt.kusto import KustoManagementClient
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError
from azure.purview.catalog import PurviewCatalogClient
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
```